# UISwitch value changed action: unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, swift, crash, xcode8

I am using Xcode 8.1 and swift 3.0. and I am creating a UISwitch programmatically, and the code is:

```
let preconnectedSwitch = UISwitch()
        preconnectedSwitch.isOn = true
        preconnectedSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged)



func switchValueDidChange() {

        print("file:- \(#file) , fucntion:- \(#function), line:- \(#line) ")

        // print("\(sender.isOn)")

        //  UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: Constant.USER_DEFAULT_IS_CONNECTED)


    }
```

But when I change UISwitch value then application crash with this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that this is a Swift function, not an Objective-C function. Add the `@IBAction` tag to your function. That will tell the compiler to create an Objective-C function.

Comment: its not working, actually I am creating UISwitch programmatically so IBAction is not working.

Comment: Did you add the `@IBAction tag to your function`? Edit your question to show all the code that creates your switch and installs it in the view hierarchy.